# Why do some materials change to the standard pink colour in Blender 3.0.0? And how do I fix this?

Tags: materials, uv

So I opened up Blender and, for the second time, materials have suddenly changed to the standard pink colour. The materials themselves have changed to this pink colour; the doors and the floor weren't purple before and this is how I found the materials when I opened Blender. Blender was closed, it wasn't running on the background before I opened it. The textures come from Polyhaven, they're downloaded(they're not form Polyhaven's add-on). The materials come in the form of meshes. I apply them by using the drop down menu, next to the search bar, in the material properties menu. Before this happend, there were no problems with these textures. I did have the same problem with other Polyhaven materials. In the UV-Editor there isn't and wasn't a texture Furthermore I'm using Blender v.3.0.0, using Eevee as render engine. I've never had problems like this with materials, except for the case described in this text. I'm a beginner in Blender, so I'd like a detailled awnser. Thanks in Advance :)
[image]

Here you see the materials have changed to the standard purple colour. The doors have different materials than the floor: the floor has the material 'herringbone_parquet' and the doors have the material 'dark_wood'.

Comment: normally it is pink if an e.g. an image/resource is missing (because you renamed it, or moved it in another folder)

Comment: did you moved the textures folder or textures into another folder? Just one place to another? because Blender doesn^t recognize textures if they moved. Maybe try to relocate textures?

Answer (score 1):

The pink colour indicates that Blender can't find the texture files. You can try using the <kbd>Find Missing Files</kbd> menu to locate the folder where Blender expects to find them.

(This image is from Blender 3.3.10 LTS. I assume that 3.0 is the same.)

[image]